# wkhtmltopdf content goes to the next page?

Tags: html, css, wkhtmltopdf

These are different pdf output. The first one print to file viewed by pdfviewer and the second viewed within firefox/chrome. The first output works fine but the second it pushes the content of the second td to the next page (happens only when content of textarea exceeds available space in the first page).

os: ubuntu 12.04
wkhtmltopdf version: wkhtmltopdf 0.12.0 03c001de254b857f08eba80b62d4b6490ffed41d
firefox: 23.0
google chrome version: Version 34.0.1847.132

code:

```
 css 
 textarea {
     resize: none;
     line-height: 1.5;
 }

 html
 <div>      
     <table>
         <tr>
         <td><label>GROSS/MICROSCOPIC DESCRIPTIONS</label></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><textarea></textarea></td>
     </tr>
     </table>
</div>
```

I'm not sure where the disconnect is because it works fine when saved to file?

Print to file version
[image]

Viewed within Firefox/Chrome
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`<input="textarea" />` is invalid HTML. It should be

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

See here for more info on the textarea tag https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

I recommend you use a [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to check your HTML is correct as it will pick up errors like this.

Comment: I have edited my question and tried <textarea></textarea> same results.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a CSS rule for the table worked for me, e.g.:

```
table {
            page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

This is instructing WKHTMLTOPDF to try keeping the entire element on a single page, even if moving the element to the next page should take place.

Notice the page-break-inside property is not supported by all browsers, therefore it its not a solution for all issues of this kind. If the content  is really large, so it doesn't fit on one page, this also will not help you avoid the page break.

After making the suggested change to your CSS, try rendering the HTML with the tool again.

Comment: @splucena, also, please do share all of your HTML & CSS as a code snippet so it gets a visualisation here, this way it will be much easier for me to help you further.